# Avoiding repetition in R

Tags: r, function, data-manipulation

Here is a typical problem that I have:

```
replace_letters <- function(string){
  gsub("x", "a", string)
}

string_x_new <- replace_letters("string_x")
string_y_new <- replace_letters("strxng_y")
string_z_new <- replace_letters("xstring_z")
...
```

Meaning that I'm writing a function (the function in the example is arbitrary) and then I want to apply that to an arbitrary set of objects. What is a neater way of doing this without having to repeat the function multiple times (sometimes I have long lists of 10-15 calls to the same function for different objects)?

Comment: Why are the objects not in a vector?

Comment: Because I'm a noob. Care to illustrate?

Comment: `chartr('x', 'a', strings)` using `strings` in @CactusWoman 's answer

Answer (score 3):

Put your strings in a vector using c("string_x", "strxng_y", "xstring_z") then use an apply function
Example:

```
strings<-c("string_x", "strxng_y", "xstring_z")

replace_letters <- function(string){
  gsub("x", "a", string)
}

strings <- sapply(strings, replace_letters)
```

Comment: `gsub("x","a",strings)` also works (though your answer illustrates an approach that will work more generally).

Comment: Yeah, but I think the asker was looking for a more general answer. That works for gsub but not for all functions

Comment: @Frank, @CactusWoman: yes, `gsub` is not the point of the question, rather how to avoid calling functions multiple times manually

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vectors of the objects you'd like to apply the function to. Let's take your example:

```
new.strings <- sapply(c("string_x", "string_y", "string_z"), replace_letters)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of R's vectorization:

```
strings<-c("string_x", "strxng_y", "xstring_z")
replace_letters(strings)
## [1] "string_a"  "strang_y"  "astring_z"
```

Comment: does this mean that the `sapply` proposed by others is unnecessary?